# How to override a base template in prestashop 1.5.6

Tags: prestashop-1.5

> Notice: Undefined index: ordered_adr_fields in
>   /var/www/html/cache/smarty/compile/76/8d/40/768d40554ed8aa8182f7dc4e72296b202eabd2b0.file.sample.tpl.php
>   on line 180
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/cache/smarty/compile/76/8d/40/768d40554ed8aa8182f7dc4e72296b202eabd2b0.file.sample.tpl.php
>   on line 180

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override a base template file through a module, you can only do that by directly editing the file you want to alter.